# Where do I find Greater Globe of Invulnerability?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, content-identification, witch

At twelfth level, a Wisdom patron Witch adds *Greater Globe of Invulnerability* to her spell list, which is presumably a better version of the *Globe of Invulnerability* spell.  Unfortunately, no such spell can be found in the CRB nor Ultimate Magic.  Where is this spell recorded, and why don't Wisdom witches gain the regular 6th level *Globe of Invulnerability* spell instead?

Answer (score 8):

Greater Globe of Invulnerability doesn't exist. The designers most likely meant regular [Globe of Invulnerability](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/coreRulebook/spells/globeOfInvulnerability.html#globe-of-invulnerability).

A wisdom witch would learn "Greater GoI" at the time when other patrons learn 6th level spells. I can't find any reference to this spell on any SRD or website. Furthermore, looking on Paizo's [official site](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/advancedPlayersGuide/baseClasses/witch.html) for the witch, the link under Globe of Invulnerability (greater) leads to the entry for the 6th level spell Globe of Invulnerability. This leads me to believe this was a misprint that was carried forward.

Given the pattern of progression from lesser to normal, once could conceive of a Greater version that is level 8 and blocks spells of 5th level and lower, but it would be homebrew.